# How do I stop the scroll right or remove the nav bar when its not pressed?

Tags: html, css

This is my css. Even after setting overflow-x to hidden, the mobile version user is still able to scroll to the right. It looks terrible. How do I stop that scroll. What are the reasons my overflow-x:hidden is not working. I've attached some images for reference as well.
CSS code below[THESE ARE THE IMAGES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss7wF.jpg)

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){

    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
            position: absolute;
            right:0px;
            height: 92vh;
            top: 15vh;
            background-color:rgb(44, 37, 37);
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            width: 50%;
            transform: translateX(100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem caused by when inner div greeter width then outer width . Or using unnecessary row (for bootstarp) .So at first need to check your html code .